# Why do I still get the buy button instead of the share one after buying an App?

Tags: 8.1, store

I use [Nextgen Reader](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nextgen-reader/643381de-4724-e011-854c-00237de2db9e) on my Windows 8.1 Pro (Update 1) desktop and on my Windows Phone 8.1 (release 8.10.12393.890) Lumia 620 phone.

I bought the App today from the desktop. If I check on the store I see the App as *installed*:

[image: screenshot from the Windows Store]

If I check on windowsphone.com I see the App as *already owned*:

[image: screenshot from the web]

**But** if I check the App on the phone I still can press the button *buy*:

[image: screenshot from the phone]

Usually when I buy an App the *buy* button is changed in the *share* button:

[image: screenshot from the phone (Metrotube)]

The App is an universal app, so it should follow the rule: buy once and run on multiple devices (Windows or Windows Phone).

I don't want to try to press the buy button on the phone because I don't want to risk to be charged twice for the same App and have to ask assistance for a refund.

Can someone please explain me if this behavior is normal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the reinstall button, from the website version of the store?

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Please, convert your comment in an aswer, I would accept it gladly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phone is showing [ buy ] only because the licence hasn't been synchronised with the phone - you've got two options:

1. Pressing [ buy ] will synchronise the licence, and install the app without incurring additional charge.
2. Using the web store to push the install to your phone

Answer (score 1):

You still see the buy button as you don't have the app installed on your phone yet. When you hit buy the phone will check the store if you have already paid for the (universal) app and then let you download it. Afterwards you'll see the share button.

Comment: I already have the App on my phone, I used for it a while in trial mode. Does the rest of your answer remain valid? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, when you try to buy the app, you should just see a confirmation that you already paid for it and the full version will be unlocked.

Comment: I already solved the problem by following the suggestion in the [@Roland Shaw](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/106/rowland-shaw)'s comment, but thanks anyway.